# Distributing dimes to 2 groups of people such that each member of one group gets at least one

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions

I have a study question that I have the answer for, but I just can't understand how or why it is the answer.

The question is: $n$ dimes are distributed to $y$ young people and $o$ old people. Every young person must get a dime, but not every old person must get a dime. How many possible combinations are there?

The answer is $$n + o - 1 \choose o + y - 1$$

Can anyone explain to me how this is?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_i$ be the number of dimes that are given to the  $i$-th young people for $i=1,2, \ldots y$ and $z_j$ the number of dimes that are given to the $j$-th old people, for $j=1,2,\ldots o$. Then the possible combinations are equal to the number of integer solutions of the equation $$x_1+x_2+\ldots +x_y+ z_1+z_2+\ldots+z_o=n$$ subject to the constraints $1\le x_i$ and $0\le z_j$. Setting $m_i=x_i-1$ the above equation can be written equivalently as $$m_1+m_2+\ldots +m_y+ z_1+z_2+\ldots+z_o=n-y$$ subject to the constraints $0\le m_i,z_j$ It is [well known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) that the number of integer solutions to this equation is equal to $$\dbinom{n-y+y+o-1}{n-y}=\dbinom{n+o-1}{o}=\dbinom{n+o-1}{n-1}$$ where $n=o+y$.